# How can I configure my mouse pad features on 14.04 LTS?

Tags: drivers, mouse-scroll

I can't scroll up or down by my mouse pad. Does it need a driver ? or something else ? any solution please ?

Comment: Could you please add some information please : what's your mousepad ? Brand, type, model ? Your laptop model, at least ?

Comment: You should provide more info to help us help you. Check out [this wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection) for guidence. As is, the question does not contain anything we can work on.

Comment: thank you Mike for guiding me, I've read that wiki you gave me and it was very helpful, now my touchpad is scrolling.

Comment: @MrVaykadji thank you for passing by :) I solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it scolls using two fingers. You can change this behaviour in System Settings.

Comment: I didn't knew that till I read the touchpad wiki ! thank you